# Calculate average of entries in same table mysql

Tags: mysql, diff, average, datediff

I have a bunch of entries in a table that look like the following

```
|id  | agency_id|old_status|new_statusts|timestamp         |contact_id|alter_type  |last_mod_by|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|968 |4926185635|  Verified|  Verified  |2016-11-2210:46:56|       969|LeadAdded   |          1|
|4274|4926185635|  Verified|  Verified  |2017-01-1410:46:56|       969|NoteAdded   |          1|
|4275|4926185635|  Verified|  Quoted    |2017-01-2110:46:56|       969|StatusChange|          1|
```

What I am trying to do is get a cumulative average of time it takes to from the time it was added to the time it was Verified as well as verified to quoted.

I have looked around through different entries on this site and can't seem to find something that fits.

Effectively what is happening is an entry gets put in when a lead is added (row id 968) then another is added when the lead status is changed from added to Verified (row id 4275) there are tons of these with the unique values being contact_id and agency_id

I want to get the average of all of the entries from Lead Added to Verified

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You missed the timestamp column name. I've edited your question to add it.

Comment: Thank you, it is names ts, I thought I included it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: What would the data look like when the new_status moves to verified?

Comment: It is shown above. Effectively what is happening is an entry gets put in when a lead is added (row id 968) then another is added when the lead status is changed from added to Verified (row id 4275) there are tons of these with the unique values being contact_id and agency_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the difference between the `leadAdded` and the `statusChange` to "Quoted".  This suggests conditional aggregation or a join:

```
select avg(datediff(tq.ts, tv.ts)) as avg_time_to_quote
from t tv join
     t tq
     on tv.agency_id = tq.agency_id and
        tv.alter_type = 'LeadAdded' and
        tq.alter_type = 'StatusChange' and
        tq.new_status = 'Quoted';
```

Comment: I was getting null result until I removed Status Changed

Now I get this, is it in seconds?

mysql> select avg(datediff(tq.ts, tv.ts)) as avg_time_to_quote
    -> from lead_history tv join
    ->      lead_history tq
    ->      on tv.agency_id = tq.agency_id and
    ->         tv.alter_type = 'Lead Added' and
    ->         tq.new_status = 'Quoted';
+-------------------+
| avg_time_to_quote |
+-------------------+
|           58.4144 |
+-------------------+